# Memory management with RxJS Observable.concatMap?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm new to RxJS and so still learning how to use the library. The documentation for `concatMap` gives the following warning:

> Warning: if source values arrive endlessly and faster than their
>   corresponding inner Observables can complete, it will result in memory
>   issues as inner Observables amass in an unbounded buffer waiting for
>   their turn to be subscribed to.

This is a problem for me because I have a memory intensive but fast concatMap feeding a slow concatMap. It's set up like this:

```
let uploadObs = Observable.range(0, blockCount).concatMap(blockIndex => {
    // This part is fast and memory intensive. I'd like to use
    // a bounded buffer here or something similar to control
    // memory utilization

    let blockReaderObs = ...;
    // ... read a block from a large file object in blockReaderObs
    return blockReaderObs;
}).concatMap((blockData, index) => {
    // This part involves a POST so is much slower than reading a
    // file block
    let objFromBlockData = someTransformation(blockData);
    return this.http.post(someUrl, objFromBlockData)
        .map(transformResponse);
});
```

What is the right approach to dealing with this kind of problem in RxJS?

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic producer-consumer problem.
You can use backpressure operators to limit the number of elements being sent in for processing. See [controlled streams](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/backpressure.md#controlled-observables).

Comment: `controlled` only exists for RxJS 4

Comment: Not much documentation on backpressure in RxJS5

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using concatMap and concatAll. I realized that I was creating way too many observables that were waiting to be subscribed to.

This answer in a separate SO discussion was helpful in writing my own solution to limit how much I would put into a concatMap:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40845089/181961